# What is the difference between geom_line(stat="hline") and geom_hline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw a horizontal line `yintercept = mean(y)` of my data (x, y)

`geom_line(stat="hline", linetype="dotted", yintercept="mean")`  works fine, but

`geom_hline(linetype="dotted", yintercept="mean")` doesn't work for me?

I wonder what are the difference between these 2 functions? I thought `geom_hline` = `geom_line` + `stat_hline`. Is it not?

#### Update

Answered here [Is there any difference between `geom_a(stat="b", ...)` and `stat_b(geom="a",...)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786161/is-there-any-difference-between-geom-astat-b-and-stat-bgeom-a)

`geom_hline` is just weird!

Comment: do you have a minimal example?

Answer (score 5):

`geom_line` works with your original data and is mainly designed to connect points, or otherwise characterise the data. You have instructed it to take the mean of the y-values to create a horizontal line.

`geom_hline` is merely an annotation. You need to specify the y-intercept explicitly. It only sees `"mean"` here as a character, rather than a function to use. You would need to write:

```
geom_hline(linetype="dotted", yintercept=mean(y))
```