# Is there any difference between `geom_a(stat="b", ...)` and `stat_b(geom="a",...)`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have seen both usages, yet I don't know the difference between 2 in practical.

And, why

```
stat_vline(xintercept="mean", geom="vline") # this works
```

But

```
geom_vline(xintercept="mean", stat="vline") # this doesn't work
```

Does that mean after passing `mean` to a next layer which is `vline` in this case, the function becomes character? Is this behaviour general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have found a bug. If you specify the aesthetics mapping (again) it works:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p + geom_vline(aes(x=wt, y=mpg), xintercept="mean", stat="vline")
```

Typical for `ggplot2` documentation is somewhat sparse, which makes it difficult to judge if this is intentional.

Comment: I augmented an existing bug report for ggplot with this: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/426